# The solutions of the diophantine equation $z^x=1+(z-1)y^2$

Tags: number-theory, exponential-diophantine-equations

I'm trying to determine the positive integer solutions of the diophantine equation $z^x=1+(z-1)y^2$. This equation can be written also as
$$y^2=\frac{z^x-1}{z-1}=\sum_{i=0}^{x-1}z^i$$
Trivial solutions $(x,y,z)$ are:
$$(0,0,m)\;\;\;(1,1,m)\;\;\;(2,m,m^2-1)$$
Other two solutions are:
$$(5,11,3)\;\;\;(4,20,7)$$
Is it possible to prove that all the solutions are the ones mentioned above?

Comment: This is a special case of the Nagell-Ljunggren equation, where it's $y^q$ with $q \geq 2$. Even though this equation hasn't been completely solved, the case of $q=2$ was proved by Ljunggren to have precisely the solutions you mention.
See this [MathOverflow post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/206645/on-a-result-attributed-to-w-ljunggren-and-t-nagell) for a link to Ljungrren's orginal paper and a translation.

Comment: Also see this [post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/58697/a-geometric-series-equalling-a-power-of-an-integer) for an overview on the further developments on the equation.

Comment: Quick observation, but probably not terribly useful, if $z=1 \mod p$ then $x$ and $y$ are not divisible by $p$ either by the lifting the exponent lemma.